# Append element to binary file

Tags: python, numpy

My goal is: Open a **binary** file, store (append) every 100 values into this file, and continue doing so until finishing. To do so, I use the following simple loop to simulate that:

```
import numpy as np
import random

alist=[]
c = 1

for i in range(1000):
    alist.append(i)
    if i == (c*100):
        np.array(alist).tofile("file.bin")
        print alist
        c = c + 1
        alist[:] = [] # clear the list before continuing
```

However, when I check the size of `file.bin`, I feel numpy does not append rather it is replacing which is not what I want. How to fix that?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, `np.ndarray.tofile` overwrites the file on each invocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course `numpy` is replacing/overwriting your old data every time you (re-)open the file for writing. This is almost universal behavior of most `tofile()` like functions (and not only in numpy).

Solution: Open a file handle for writing before the loop and pass that to `tofile()` function. Like this:

```
import numpy as np
import random

alist=[]
c = 1
with open("file.bin", "wb") as f: # or choose 'w+' mode - read "open()" documentation
    for i in range(1000):
        alist.append(i)
        if i == (c*100):
            np.array(alist).tofile(f)
            print alist
            c = c + 1
            alist[:] = [] # clear the list before continuing
```

Now the code opens the file before entering the loop and `tofile()` method re-uses an already opened file handle instead of re-opening and thus overwriting an existing file (created in the run of the loop).

Comment: Kindly, may I know how to implement your solution? Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreciate it