# How to save array iteratively to file in python?

Tags: python, file, numpy

I want to do in a for loop something like this:

```
for i in range(n):
   x = vector()
   np.savetxt('t.txt', x, newline=" ")
```

but I want to save each array x as a new line in my file, but this doesn't happen with the code above, can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: How about `newline="\n"`, which according to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) is set by default?

Comment: _"...but this doesn't happen with the code above"_ What is the problem with the code? What *does* happen?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with open('t.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(n):
        x = vector()
        np.savetxt(f, x, newline=" ")
        f.write('\n')
```

That is, pass an already open file handle to the `numpy`'s `savetxt` function. This way it will not overwrite existing content. Also see [Append element to binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222878/append-element-to-binary-file/45222964#45222964)

Comment: @Rael consider accepting this answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like (untested!):

```
for i in range(n):
    x = vector()
    with open("t.txt", "a") as f:  # "a" for append!
        f.write(np.array_str(x))
```

There are some decisions to make:

- opening/closing the file in each iteration vs. keeping the file-handler open
- using np.array_str / np.array_repr / np.array2string

This of course is **based on the assumption, that you can't wait to grab all data before writing all at once! (online-setting)**