# how can I save more than one data in a single out put file separately using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

How can I save more than one data consecutively in a single output file using `numpy`? For example, the out put file should contain

```
Matrix A 
"and below that some text and the another"
matrix B
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/47104306

Answer (score 2):

You simply pass an open file handle to [`numpy.savetxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.zeros((3,3))

In [3]: b = np.ones((5,6))

In [4]: with open('mix.txt', 'w') as f:
   ...:     np.savetxt(f, a, fmt='%g')
   ...:     f.write('my comment followed by a new array:\n')
   ...:     np.savetxt(f, b, fmt='%g')
   ...:     

In [5]: !more mix.txt
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
my comment followed by a new array:
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: @Surajit If you think this a good answer, and it helped solve your question, don't forget to [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You can always change your mind later if another user posts a better answer.